# Formatear elementos de una lista

Tags: lista, python-3.7, formato

Tengo un pequeño problema con una lista y un pequeño formato que quiero darle:

Tengo esto:

```
Lista = ['Nombre Uno','Nombre Dos','Nombre Tres','Nombre Cuatro']
```

**Y necesito exactamente esto:**

```
Lista_ = ['Nombre_Uno','Nombre_Dos','Nombre_Tres','Nombre_Cuatro']
```

Los valores de la segunda lista corresponden a la primera pero cambiando los espacios en blanco entre las palabras por el caracter `_`. Tan sólo eso.

Saludos y muchas gracias!

Comment: `Lista_ = list(x.replace(' ', '_') for x in Lista)` usando [comprension de listas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No soy experto pero quizás esto te puede ayudar, ya que es bastante facil utilizando `replace`.

```py
lista = ['Nombre Uno','Nombre Dos','Nombre Tres','Nombre Cuatro'];

def refactor():
  for index, l in enumerate(lista):
    lista[index] = l.replace(" ", "_");


refactor();
```

Simplemente he recorrido el array con un `for`, donde en cada elemento, usando `replace` reemplaza **todas** las coincidencias, en este caso un espacio por un guión bajo.

Puedes echar un vistazo a la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).